# libgdx update label text and position simultaniously

Tags: java, android, libgdx, slider, label

What I'm trying to do is add a label to follow a slider knob and display the knob's value.  I currently have a vertical slider and a label stacked inside a table cell.  I'm able to position the label to where the knob is and update it's text correctly but am having a problem while moving the knob.

When I move the knob I can make the label follow it as long as I don't update the text.  But if I update the text then the label re-centers itself in the cell till the knob has stopped moving at which point it places itself on the knob.

How do I make it so that the label doesn't reposition while it's updating text?

Here's some sample code of what I have going on:

```
public class OptionsWindow implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private Slider slider;
    private Label label;

    private Skin textSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/skin.json"),
        new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins/text.pack")));
    private Skin sliderSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/skin.json"),
        new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins/text.pack")));

    private min = 1, max = 2;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();
        table = new Table();
        slider = new Slider(min, max, 0.001f, true, sliderSkin);
        label = new Label(""), textSkin);

        table.stack(label, slider).height(1000);
        table.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(table);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        label.setY(slider.getValue() - min);
        label.setText(slider.getValue());

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

I've done a lot of searching for an answer to this question but have yielded no results.  I have also tried placing the label in a container and moving the container while changing the label text, but the same result happens.  I'm sure somebody had done this before.  It seems like something people would want.  Please, any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried altering the text before setting the y-coordinate?

Comment: Yes I have. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I came up with a work around.  It would seem that labels move back to their cell alignment position while updating text.  to solve this I simply placed my label in a table with a row on either side like so:

```
Table subTable = new Table();
subTable.add().row();
subTable.add(label).row();
subTable.add();
```

Then in render I calculate new height values for the exterior cells and apply them:

```
float topH, botH;
// Calculate heights
topH = (1 - slider.getPercent()) * parentTable.getHeight();
botH = slider.getPercent() * parentTable.getHeight();

// Apply heights to exterior table cells
subTable.getCells().get(0).height(topH);
subTable.getCells().get(2).height(botH);

// Update label text
label.setText(slider.getValue());
```

This is just a simple form of what I have.  You'll want to take into account the label height to get it to position correctly.  Also if you want it to follow with the slider at the slider's set animateDuration, you'll want to use getVisualPercent() instead of getPercent().  However this causes issues when your finger flies out of the cell.  For some reason the visual percent is linked to where the slider knob is when your finger leaves the cell, not where it ends up.

My work around for this was to just set the animateDuration to 0.0f and just use getPercent().  If I or someone comes up with a solution to the getVisualPercent() option, then that would be nice to have posted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Never done it before, I always show the amount in a label next to or above the slider to give feedback. But the result you are after gives a nice touch. Did you try adding a `ChangeListener` to your slider? Everytime the slider changes this would be called. So if you insert the new position and text in there it should be updating correctly.

```
        //Slider has to be "final" for the listener.
        final Slider slider = new Slider(0, 10, 1, true, skin);
        slider.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                label.setY(slider.getValue() - min);
                label.setText(slider.getValue());
            }
        });
```

This does not need to be in your render method. It's a listener so whenever something happens the listener listens for it will execute.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.  It kind of made it worse.  with this the label now hardly ever even changed it's position and even when it happened to change, it would still go back to the center of the table cell while updating it's text.

Comment: Have to check this out myself tomorrow.  CET here.